# Enviar dados tipo array em Webservice feito em NuSOAP

Tags: php, web-service, soap, array-multidimensional

Fala galera, blza?

Estou desenvolvendo um webservice php em soap, estou usando a biblioteca nuSOAP, os testes com tipo simples foram bem sucedidos porém agora preciso testar com tipos complexos como arrays más não consigo fazer funcionar, da erro na transmissão, já inclui um comando para habilitar este tipo más estou fazendo algo de errado, se alguem puder ajudar eu agradeço.

Descricao do erro gerado:

```
SOAP-ENV:Client: error in msg parsing:
XML error parsing SOAP payload on line 1: Space required
```

A estrutura que envio e preciso receber é essa:

```
array (size=1)
  'itens' => 
    array (size=3)
      'suco' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => int 1
          1 => string '1.90' (length=4)
      'coca cola' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => int 1
          1 => string '4.99' (length=4)
      'miojo' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => int 5
          1 => string '3.99' (length=4)
```

No arquivo servidor.php inclui este comando para habilitar o tipo complexo:

```
$servidor->wsdl->addComplexType(
    'onItens',
    'complexType',
    'struct',
    '',
    'SOAP-ENC:Array',
    array(),
    array(
        'itens' => 'SOAP-ENC:arrayType',
        'wsdl:arrayType' => 'xsd:string[]'
    )
);

$servidor->register(
    'WS.onLancamentos',
    array('itens'=>'tns:onItens'),
    array('retorno'=>'xsd:string'),
    $namespace,
    $namespace.'#lancamentos',
    'rpc',
    'encoded',
    'Lancamento dos itens comprados na PEGGOU'
);
```

**Obs**: Quando o array principal 'itens' fica somente com um elemento então funciona más o numero de itens é indefinido, logo preciso configurar para funcionar com mais elementos.

Answer (score 1):

EUREKA! Problema resolvido.

Depois de muitos testes e debugs descobri o motivo do problema.

O problema estava simplesmente em um dos elementos do array.

A chave 'coca cola' estava dando todo esse erro, o espaço entre as palavras era que causava o erro.

A solução foi simplesmente substituir o espaço por um underline.

Ainda bem que esse problema aconteceu agora pois se acontece na produção dae seria tenso. Ufa!

Fica ae o registro caso alguém tenha um problema parecido com esse que tive.